Unable to save data in the firebase realtime database in the react project?
I have created an react project, here is the code:-
AuthContext.js:-
    import { useContext, createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import {
      GoogleAuthProvider,
      signInWithPopup,
      signInWithRedirect,
      signOut,
      onAuthStateChanged,
    } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { auth, databaseRef } from '../firebase'; 
    
    const AuthContext = createContext();
    
    export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    
      const googleSignIn = () => {
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        signInWithRedirect(auth, provider); // Choose your preferred sign-in method
      };
    
      const logOut = async () => { // Make logOut async for potential errors
        try {
          await signOut(auth);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error signing out:', error);
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
          setUser(currentUser);
          console.log('User', currentUser);
        });
    
        return unsubscribe;
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ googleSignIn, logOut, user, databaseRef }}>
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      );
    };

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

Account.jsx:-
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const Account = () => {
  const { user, databaseRef } = UserAuth();
  const [userIds, setUserIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserIds = async () => {
      const snapshot = await databaseRef.child('userids').once('value');
      const data = snapshot.val();
      setUserIds(Object.values(data || {}));
    };

    fetchUserIds();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Navbar url='/signin' text='Log out' />
      <div className='w-[300px] m-auto'>
        <h1 className='text-center text-2xl font-bold pt-12'>Account</h1>
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {user?.displayName}</p>
          {userIds.length > 0 && (
            <ul>
              {userIds.map((id) => (
                <li key={id}>{id}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;

Signin.jsx:-
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GoogleButton } from 'react-google-button';
import { UserAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';

const Signin = () => {
  const { googleSignIn, user, databaseRef } = UserAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await googleSignIn();
      const userObj = result.user;

      const userId = userObj.uid;
      console.log('Attempting to save user ID:', userId); // Log before saving
      await databaseRef.child('userids').push(userId);
      console.log('User ID saved successfully:', userId);

  navigate('/account');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during sign-in or saving user ID:', error);
    }
  };

   useEffect(() => {
     if (user != null) {
       // navigate('/account');
     }
   }, [user]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar url='/' text='Home' />
      <h1 className='text-center text-3xl font-bold py-8'>Sign in</h1>
      <div className='max-w-[240px] m-auto py-4'>
        <GoogleButton onClick={handleGoogleSignIn} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signin;

firebase.js:-
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref } from 'firebase/database';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "QIazSyDO132QtFu798QoI472h6pb2KzdXZExyQs",
  authDomain: "trail-24.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://trail-24-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "trail-24",
  storageBucket: "trail-24.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1011673947249",
  appId: "1:1011943747984:web:08ee8dd634ffe87c55f915",
  measurementId: "G-FSXIJTC9PX"
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getDatabase(app);
export const databaseRef = ref(db);

This is the console log:-
    User null
Signin.jsx:23 Error during sign-in or saving user ID: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at Object.handleGoogleSignIn [as onClick] (Signin.jsx:14:1)
handleGoogleSignIn @ Signin.jsx:23
await in handleGoogleSignIn (async)
(anonymous) @ GoogleButton.js:108
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4161
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4210
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4274
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4288
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9038
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9070
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9083
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9094
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9285
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26096
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3988
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9284
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6462
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6454
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6427
Show 16 more frames
Show less
Navigated to https://trails-22.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=QIazSyDO132QtFu798QoI472h6pb2KzdXZExyQs&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaRedirect&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fsignin&v=9.6.11&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile
api.js?onload=__iframefcb691612:10 
        
        
       GET https://trails-22.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/init.json 404 (Not Found)
Hj.send @ iframe_form_check.js:259
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:556
K @ iframe_form_check.js:170
es.zf @ iframe_form_check.js:556
fs @ iframe_form_check.js:557
g @ iframe_form_check.js:625
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:626
a @ iframe_form_check.js:168
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:168
c @ iframe_form_check.js:168
e.kc @ iframe_form_check.js:176
jh @ iframe_form_check.js:179
fh @ iframe_form_check.js:179
K.jk @ iframe_form_check.js:178
a @ iframe_form_check.js:168
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:168
c @ iframe_form_check.js:168
Qg @ iframe_form_check.js:169
a (async)
Jg @ iframe_form_check.js:169
bh @ iframe_form_check.js:175
K.then @ iframe_form_check.js:173
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:626
a @ iframe_form_check.js:168
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:168
c @ iframe_form_check.js:168
e.kc @ iframe_form_check.js:176
jh @ iframe_form_check.js:179
fh @ iframe_form_check.js:179
K.jk @ iframe_form_check.js:178
a @ iframe_form_check.js:168
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:168
c @ iframe_form_check.js:168
Qg @ iframe_form_check.js:169
a (async)
Jg @ iframe_form_check.js:169
bh @ iframe_form_check.js:175
K.then @ iframe_form_check.js:173
mt.qb @ iframe_form_check.js:624
mt.start @ iframe_form_check.js:623
(anonymous) @ iframe_form_check.js:634
(anonymous) @ api.js?onload=__iframefcb691612:10
Show 39 more frames
Show less
Navigated to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1011938947984-ohu9p7u73ihdqvhi2sr9d3t2tl42kmun.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftrails-22.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fhandler&state=AMbdmDmFH3jre6VTr-qc6HyTkYZWC-zz_CJ_zn4EyBZGd28mJ8oz-flM3tRm1_PRn5AaC3Envhmv_42vjhuQo9cIny82ZDkvYUSoZszyYDWQOHN_ZkLH-faQ6PpZ-1Gefbzh4LinwHTFCM3Gov_WyGhG8kl7ayy5NKxMkPMUJnqV7lQ0QRXaaalTAgNUWvUscZJdRVOLPF82SaIFyh3uHBAvoUCpHmyed5P-vFCBq5iEeuWRP_eGAInDJikjawyUQZFWnnOgVUst4c7NHeLi_iy0VRhrLcBXchEjhdjoGTh2yeidWIiUaaYX6QJnBQK3ENLwoTsXhl3nfdX1aw&scope=openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20profile&context_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000
5Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
Navigated to https://trails-22.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?state=AMbdmDmFH3jre6VTr-qc6HyTkYZWC-zz_CJ_zn4EyBZGd28mJ8oz-flM3tRm1_PRn5AaC3Envhmv_42vjhuQo9cIny82ZDkvYUSoZszyYDWQOHN_ZkLH-faQ6PpZ-1Gefbzh4LinwHTFCM3Gov_WyGhG8kl7ayy5NKxMkPMUJnqV7lQ0QRXaaalTAgNUWvUscZJdRVOLPF82SaIFyh3uHBAvoUCpHmyed5P-vFCBq5iEeuWRP_eGAInDJikjawyUQZFWnnOgVUst4c7NHeLi_iy0VRhrLcBXchEjhdjoGTh2yeidWIiUaaYX6QJnBQK3ENLwoTsXhl3nfdX1aw&code=4%2F0AeaYSHC6o8WykWTv1DWN0O83Bwd7QZcWw6nYM_ruo_ATobQYvk4RjthTfBhKL6XAfomKsA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=2&prompt=none
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/signin
react refresh:6 Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
6Third-party cookie will be blocked. Learn more in the Issues tab.
AuthContext.js:32 User UserImpl {providerId: 'firebase', proactiveRefresh: ProactiveRefresh, reloadUserInfo: {…}, reloadListener: null, uid: 'RdMQaBouH4RY5rVozaw7o9dSAro1', …}

Firebase Database rules:-
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

I am new to react and I have already tried different ways to save this data in the realtime database of firebase, but I am successfully login the user but I am unable to save the data, I am also not getting anything in the console of Signin.jsx file, which I have created for saving the data.
Someone please help me.

There is way too much code in your question to reasonably read. While it's of course always possible that somebody spots the problem and answers, chances of that drastically go up if you take the time to create an isolated reproduction of the problem and share that instead.

I have removed the unused code to save data to the realtime database, now there is code of only the files which I have used for saving the data

Your googleSignIn function doesn't return any value:
  const googleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithRedirect(auth, provider); // Choose your preferred sign-in method
  };

So that means this won't work:
  const result = await googleSignIn();
  const userObj = result.user;

To make that last snippet work, make sure you return a value from googleSignIn.

I have updated the code based on your answer but still I am getting the other error, I have updated the question.

First off: does the explanation of why your previous code didn't work make sense? And is it clear why the change in my answer makes it work? ---
If you get another error now, it means that my answer solved the problem you posted. If you now get another error, it means that you have a new problem. Please don't change your question in this way after somebody has responded to it, as it makes the entire page useless to future visitors.

Okay, I will add new question
